# On Urysohn subsequence principle

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let ${X_n}$ be a sequence of scalar random variables, and let ${X}$ be another scalar random variable.

(Urysohn subsequence principle) Suppose that every subsequence ${X_{n_j}}$ of ${X_n}$ has a further subsequence ${X_{n_{j_k}}}$ that converges to ${X}$ in probability, then ${X_n}$ also converges to ${X}$ in probability.
Does the Urysohn subsequence principle still hold if “in probability” is replaced with “almost surely” throughout?

**Question:** One can establish the original principle with the fact that every sequence not converging to $0$ has a subsequence bounded away from $0$. As this argument fails to work if “in probability” is replaced with “almost surely” throughout, the answer should be no. Yet can we have an explicit counterexample to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $(X_n)$ be any sequence of random variables which converges in probability but not almost surely. Any subsequence of this  converges in probability which implies that there is a further subsequence which converges almost surely. So this is a counter-example for your statement.

An explicit example is obatined by arranging the indicator functions of the intervals $[\frac {i-1}{n}, \frac i {n})$ in  a sequence.

Comment: The typewriter sequence can serve as a counter example as well.